# Socket connection is messed up?? ConnectException in Java

Tags: java, web-services, sockets

I'm trying to set up my first sample web project for the sake of learning how to do it.  I have 4 classes in a package called "com.java24hours.ws".  I'm am trying to run the SquareRootClient class in eclipse as a java application. I am getting a java.net.ConnectException (i posted the error log after my classes).  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

SquareRootClient

```
package com.java24hours.ws;

import java.net.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.*;
import javax.xml.ws.*;

class SquareRootClient {
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:5335/service?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName(
            "http://ws.java24hours.com/",
            "SquareRoorServerImplService"
        );
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        SquareRootServer srs = service.getPort(SquareRootServer.class);

        System.out.println(srs.getTime());
        System.out.println(srs.getSquareRoot(625D));
    }
}
```

SquareRootServer

```
package com.java24hours.ws;

import javax.jws.*;
import javax.jws.soap.*;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.*;

@WebService

@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)

public interface SquareRootServer {
    // get the square root of a number
    @WebMethod double getSquareRoot(double input);

    // get the current time and date as a string
    @WebMethod String getTime();

}
```

SquareRootServerImpl

```
package com.java24hours.ws;

import java.util.*;
import javax.jws.*;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.java24hours.ws.SquareRootServer")

public class SquareRootServerImpl implements SquareRootServer {

    public double getSquareRoot(double input) {
        return Math.sqrt(input);
    }

    public String getTime() {
        Date now = new Date();
        return now.toString();
    }
}
```

SquareRootServerPublisher

```
package com.java24hours.ws;

import javax.xml.ws.*;


public class SquareRootServerPublisher {

    public static void main (String [] arguments ){
        SquareRootServerImpl srsi = new SquareRootServerImpl();
        Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:5335/service", srsi);
    }
}
```

Console (log):

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://127.0.0.1:5335/service?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Connection refused: connect.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.java24hours.ws.SquareRootClient.main(SquareRootClient.java:14)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Can you try to execute the 'telnet localhost 5335' or access the the WSDL from the browser?

Comment: what is telnet localhost?  I cant access the wsdl from a browser (is this because the server doesnt exist until i run the app?).  I also allowed the 5335 port in windows firewall but that didnt do anything

Comment: That could be the problem. Run the server and check the WSDL from your browser. If it is available, then execute your client program.

Comment: Siva, Thank you.  Could you explain to me what the basic roles of Client, ServerImplementation, Server, Server Publisher are?  Would you mind posting as an answer so i can accept it?  My biggest misconception is that i dont understand why we need one calss for ServerImplementation and another for the Server